# Aurelia http-fetch handle error

Tags: http, aurelia

I have an application I am creating using Aurelia. I wish to simplify the http responses.

I have de following code:

```
@inject(HttpClient)
export class Api {
  constructor(httpClient) {
    this.http = httpClient;
    this.http.configure(config => {
      config
        .withBaseUrl(window.sessionStorage.getItem('baseUrl'))
        .withDefaults({
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'
          }
        })
        .withInterceptor({
          request: handleRequest,
          response: handleResponse
        });
     })
  }

  get(url, params) {
    return this.http.fetch(url, {method: 'get', body: params});
  }

  post(url, params) {
    return this.http.fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: params});
  }
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    thown {status: response.status, data: rsponse.json() };//this not works
  }
  return response.json();
}

function handleRequest(request) {
   let token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
   if (token) {
     request.headers.append('Authorization', `bearer ${token}`);
   }
   return request;
 }
```

When the `response.ok` is `false` the response results is:

```
Object { status: 422, data: Promise }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your problem is that the data is missing from the returned object and a Promise is returned on error then you will need to wait for the promise returned from json() to resolve first. Something like:

```js
if (!response.ok) {
  response.json().then(data => {
    return {status: response.status, data: data};
  }
}
```